# Running Kafka-Manager inside Docker container on Windows

Tags: windows, docker, apache-kafka

I am following [this tutorial](https://zablo.net/blog/post/setup-apache-kafka-in-docker-on-windows/) to run Kafka inside a Docker container on windows.

When I try to launch Kafka-Manager by opening http://localhost:9000 in the browser as described there, I get ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED.

Something I think might be related is that at the first time I ran `docker-compose up`, PowerShell showed an error saying I needed to run some command first, to open a virtual machine or something like that.

Then I ran the command that PowerShell had told me and then I managed to run `docker-compose up` successfully. However the tutorial didn't mention anything about it, and since then every time I tried to run `docker-compose up` I managed to to it without running another command first, even if I closed and reopened PowerShell.

I suspect PowerShell remembers I'm connected to a virtual machine so `docker-compose up` runs Kafka inside a virtual machine, and therefore I can't reach Kafka-Manager in the browser, although I see shows the following message:

> kafkamanager     | [info] p.c.s.NettyServer - Listening for HTTP on
>   /0.0.0.0:9000

**Edit:**

`docker logs` for kafka container:

```
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/supervisor/options.py:296: UserWarning: Supervisord is running as root and it is searching for its configuration file in default locations (including its current working directory); you probably want to specify a "-c" argument specifying an absolute path to a configuration file for improved security.
  'Supervisord is running as root and it is searching '
2020-02-28 08:37:37,274 CRIT Supervisor running as root (no user in config file)
2020-02-28 08:37:37,274 WARN Included extra file "/etc/supervisor/conf.d/zookeeper.conf" during parsing
2020-02-28 08:37:37,274 WARN Included extra file "/etc/supervisor/conf.d/kafka.conf" during parsing
2020-02-28 08:37:37,303 INFO RPC interface 'supervisor' initialized
2020-02-28 08:37:37,303 CRIT Server 'unix_http_server' running without any HTTP authentication checking
2020-02-28 08:37:37,303 INFO supervisord started with pid 1
2020-02-28 08:37:38,306 INFO spawned: 'zookeeper' with pid 8
2020-02-28 08:37:38,308 INFO spawned: 'kafka' with pid 9
2020-02-28 08:37:39,372 INFO success: zookeeper entered RUNNING state, process has stayed up for > than 1 seconds (startsecs)
2020-02-28 08:37:39,372 INFO success: kafka entered RUNNING state, process has stayed up for > than 1 seconds (startsecs)
2020-02-28 21:16:01,095 WARN received SIGTERM indicating exit request
2020-02-28 21:16:01,095 INFO waiting for zookeeper, kafka to die
2020-02-28 21:16:02,102 INFO stopped: kafka (terminated by SIGTERM)
2020-02-28 21:16:02,442 INFO stopped: zookeeper (exit status 143)
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/supervisor/options.py:296: UserWarning: Supervisord is running as root and it is searching for its configuration file in default locations (including its current working directory); you probably want to specify a "-c" argument specifying an absolute path to a configuration file for improved security.
  'Supervisord is running as root and it is searching '
2020-02-28 21:17:50,843 CRIT Supervisor running as root (no user in config file)
2020-02-28 21:17:50,843 WARN Included extra file "/etc/supervisor/conf.d/zookeeper.conf" during parsing
2020-02-28 21:17:50,843 WARN Included extra file "/etc/supervisor/conf.d/kafka.conf" during parsing
2020-02-28 21:17:50,858 INFO RPC interface 'supervisor' initialized
2020-02-28 21:17:50,858 CRIT Server 'unix_http_server' running without any HTTP authentication checking
2020-02-28 21:17:50,859 INFO supervisord started with pid 1
2020-02-28 21:17:51,862 INFO spawned: 'zookeeper' with pid 8
2020-02-28 21:17:51,864 INFO spawned: 'kafka' with pid 9
2020-02-28 21:17:52,926 INFO success: zookeeper entered RUNNING state, process has stayed up for > than 1 seconds (startsecs)
2020-02-28 21:17:52,927 INFO success: kafka entered RUNNING state, process has stayed up for > than 1 seconds (startsecs)
2020-02-28 21:17:59,672 INFO exited: kafka (exit status 1; not expected)
2020-02-28 21:18:00,675 INFO spawned: 'kafka' with pid 297
2020-02-28 21:18:01,694 INFO success: kafka entered RUNNING state, process has stayed up for > than 1 seconds (startsecs)
2020-02-29 19:42:18,487 WARN received SIGTERM indicating exit request
2020-02-29 19:42:18,487 INFO waiting for zookeeper, kafka to die
2020-02-29 19:42:18,488 INFO stopped: kafka (terminated by SIGTERM)
2020-02-29 19:42:18,821 INFO stopped: zookeeper (exit status 143)
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/supervisor/options.py:296: UserWarning: Supervisord is running as root and it is searching for its configuration file in default locations (including its current working directory); you probably want to specify a "-c" argument specifying an absolute path to a configuration file for improved security.
  'Supervisord is running as root and it is searching '
2020-02-29 19:42:26,841 CRIT Supervisor running as root (no user in config file)
2020-02-29 19:42:26,841 WARN Included extra file "/etc/supervisor/conf.d/zookeeper.conf" during parsing
2020-02-29 19:42:26,842 WARN Included extra file "/etc/supervisor/conf.d/kafka.conf" during parsing
2020-02-29 19:42:26,854 INFO RPC interface 'supervisor' initialized
2020-02-29 19:42:26,854 CRIT Server 'unix_http_server' running without any HTTP authentication checking
2020-02-29 19:42:26,855 INFO supervisord started with pid 1
2020-02-29 19:42:27,857 INFO spawned: 'zookeeper' with pid 8
2020-02-29 19:42:27,859 INFO spawned: 'kafka' with pid 9
2020-02-29 19:42:28,903 INFO success: zookeeper entered RUNNING state, process has stayed up for > than 1 seconds (startsecs)
2020-02-29 19:42:28,903 INFO success: kafka entered RUNNING state, process has stayed up for > than 1 seconds (startsecs)
2020-02-29 19:42:34,985 INFO exited: kafka (exit status 1; not expected)
2020-02-29 19:42:35,988 INFO spawned: 'kafka' with pid 297
2020-02-29 19:42:37,014 INFO success: kafka entered RUNNING state, process has stayed up for > than 1 seconds (startsecs)
2020-02-29 19:43:20,590 WARN received SIGTERM indicating exit request
2020-02-29 19:43:20,590 INFO waiting for zookeeper, kafka to die
2020-02-29 19:43:20,590 INFO stopped: kafka (terminated by SIGTERM)
2020-02-29 19:43:20,784 INFO stopped: zookeeper (exit status 143)
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/supervisor/options.py:296: UserWarning: Supervisord is running as root and it is searching for its configuration file in default locations (including its current working directory); you probably want to specify a "-c" argument specifying an absolute path to a configuration file for improved security.
  'Supervisord is running as root and it is searching '
2020-02-29 19:45:38,600 CRIT Supervisor running as root (no user in config file)
2020-02-29 19:45:38,600 WARN Included extra file "/etc/supervisor/conf.d/zookeeper.conf" during parsing
2020-02-29 19:45:38,600 WARN Included extra file "/etc/supervisor/conf.d/kafka.conf" during parsing
2020-02-29 19:45:38,619 INFO RPC interface 'supervisor' initialized
2020-02-29 19:45:38,629 CRIT Server 'unix_http_server' running without any HTTP authentication checking
2020-02-29 19:45:38,630 INFO supervisord started with pid 1
2020-02-29 19:45:39,632 INFO spawned: 'zookeeper' with pid 8
2020-02-29 19:45:39,634 INFO spawned: 'kafka' with pid 9
2020-02-29 19:45:40,687 INFO success: zookeeper entered RUNNING state, process has stayed up for > than 1 seconds (startsecs)
2020-02-29 19:45:40,689 INFO success: kafka entered RUNNING state, process has stayed up for > than 1 seconds (startsecs)
2020-02-29 19:45:47,740 INFO exited: kafka (exit status 1; not expected)
2020-02-29 19:45:48,743 INFO spawned: 'kafka' with pid 297
2020-02-29 19:45:49,763 INFO success: kafka entered RUNNING state, process has stayed up for > than 1 seconds (startsecs)
2020-02-29 19:46:20,659 WARN received SIGTERM indicating exit request
2020-02-29 19:46:20,659 INFO waiting for zookeeper, kafka to die
2020-02-29 19:46:20,660 INFO stopped: kafka (terminated by SIGTERM)
2020-02-29 19:46:20,991 INFO stopped: zookeeper (exit status 143)
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/supervisor/options.py:296: UserWarning: Supervisord is running as root and it is searching for its configuration file in default locations (including its current working directory); you probably want to specify a "-c" argument specifying an absolute path to a configuration file for improved security.
  'Supervisord is running as root and it is searching '
2020-03-13 22:16:26,128 CRIT Supervisor running as root (no user in config file)
2020-03-13 22:16:26,128 WARN Included extra file "/etc/supervisor/conf.d/zookeeper.conf" during parsing
2020-03-13 22:16:26,128 WARN Included extra file "/etc/supervisor/conf.d/kafka.conf" during parsing
2020-03-13 22:16:26,157 INFO RPC interface 'supervisor' initialized
2020-03-13 22:16:26,162 CRIT Server 'unix_http_server' running without any HTTP authentication checking
2020-03-13 22:16:26,162 INFO supervisord started with pid 1
2020-03-13 22:16:27,164 INFO spawned: 'zookeeper' with pid 8
2020-03-13 22:16:27,167 INFO spawned: 'kafka' with pid 9
2020-03-13 22:16:28,226 INFO success: zookeeper entered RUNNING state, process has stayed up for > than 1 seconds (startsecs)
2020-03-13 22:16:28,227 INFO success: kafka entered RUNNING state, process has stayed up for > than 1 seconds (startsecs)
2020-03-13 22:16:36,496 INFO exited: kafka (exit status 1; not expected)
2020-03-13 22:16:37,499 INFO spawned: 'kafka' with pid 298
2020-03-13 22:16:38,511 INFO success: kafka entered RUNNING state, process has stayed up for > than 1 seconds (startsecs)
2020-03-13 22:17:20,939 WARN received SIGTERM indicating exit request
2020-03-13 22:17:20,940 INFO waiting for zookeeper, kafka to die
2020-03-13 22:17:20,940 INFO stopped: kafka (terminated by SIGTERM)
2020-03-13 22:17:21,268 INFO stopped: zookeeper (exit status 143)
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/supervisor/options.py:296: UserWarning: Supervisord is running as root and it is searching for its configuration file in default locations (including its current working directory); you probably want to specify a "-c" argument specifying an absolute path to a configuration file for improved security.
  'Supervisord is running as root and it is searching '
2020-03-27 21:25:59,495 CRIT Supervisor running as root (no user in config file)
2020-03-27 21:25:59,496 WARN Included extra file "/etc/supervisor/conf.d/zookeeper.conf" during parsing
2020-03-27 21:25:59,497 WARN Included extra file "/etc/supervisor/conf.d/kafka.conf" during parsing
2020-03-27 21:25:59,520 INFO RPC interface 'supervisor' initialized
2020-03-27 21:25:59,522 CRIT Server 'unix_http_server' running without any HTTP authentication checking
2020-03-27 21:25:59,523 INFO supervisord started with pid 1
2020-03-27 21:26:00,530 INFO spawned: 'zookeeper' with pid 8
2020-03-27 21:26:00,532 INFO spawned: 'kafka' with pid 9
2020-03-27 21:26:01,620 INFO success: zookeeper entered RUNNING state, process has stayed up for > than 1 seconds (startsecs)
2020-03-27 21:26:01,620 INFO success: kafka entered RUNNING state, process has stayed up for > than 1 seconds (startsecs)
```

`docker logs` for kafka manager container seems fine:

```
[info] o.a.z.ZooKeeper - Client environment:java.library.path=/usr/java/packages/lib/amd64:/usr/lib64:/lib64:/lib:/usr/lib
[info] o.a.z.ZooKeeper - Client environment:java.io.tmpdir=/tmp
[info] o.a.z.ZooKeeper - Client environment:java.compiler=<NA>
[info] o.a.z.ZooKeeper - Client environment:os.name=Linux
[info] o.a.z.ZooKeeper - Client environment:os.arch=amd64
[info] o.a.z.ZooKeeper - Client environment:os.version=4.9.93-boot2docker
[info] o.a.z.ZooKeeper - Client environment:user.name=root
[info] o.a.z.ZooKeeper - Client environment:user.home=/root
[info] o.a.z.ZooKeeper - Client environment:user.dir=/kafka-manager-1.3.3.4
[info] o.a.z.ZooKeeper - Initiating client connection, connectString=kafkaserver:2181 sessionTimeout=60000 watcher=org.apache.curator.ConnectionState@7a27a9b4
[info] o.a.z.ClientCnxn - Opening socket connection to server kafka.kafka_kafkanet/172.18.0.2:2181. Will not attempt to authenticate using SASL (unknown error)
[info] k.m.a.KafkaManagerActor - zk=kafkaserver:2181
[info] k.m.a.KafkaManagerActor - baseZkPath=/kafka-manager
[info] o.a.z.ClientCnxn - Socket connection established to kafka.kafka_kafkanet/172.18.0.2:2181, initiating session
[info] o.a.z.ClientCnxn - Session establishment complete on server kafka.kafka_kafkanet/172.18.0.2:2181, sessionid = 0x1711de33be70001, negotiated timeout = 40000
[info] k.m.a.KafkaManagerActor - Started actor akka://kafka-manager-system/user/kafka-manager
[info] k.m.a.KafkaManagerActor - Starting delete clusters path cache...
[info] k.m.a.DeleteClusterActor - Started actor akka://kafka-manager-system/user/kafka-manager/delete-cluster
[info] k.m.a.DeleteClusterActor - Starting delete clusters path cache...
[info] k.m.a.DeleteClusterActor - Adding kafka manager path cache listener...
[info] k.m.a.DeleteClusterActor - Scheduling updater for 10 seconds
[info] k.m.a.KafkaManagerActor - Starting kafka manager path cache...
[info] k.m.a.KafkaManagerActor - Adding kafka manager path cache listener...
[info] play.api.Play - Application started (Prod)
[info] p.c.s.NettyServer - Listening for HTTP on /0.0.0.0:9000
[info] k.m.a.KafkaManagerActor - Updating internal state...
[info] k.m.a.KafkaManagerActor - Updating internal state...
[info] k.m.a.KafkaManagerActor - Updating internal state...
[info] k.m.a.KafkaManagerActor - Updating internal state...
```

This log is a lot longer so I've ommited the beginning but it seems fine.

Comment: Can you edit and add your docker compose yml file in your question? And what is this command you had to run ..? Any logs helping

Comment: have you try map port of container to docker host?

Comment: @Yannick Sorry I forgot to add the link to the tutorial. I added it now.

Comment: @TuyenLuong Sorry I forgot to add the link to the tutorial. I added it now. Yes I did ports: 9000:9000.

Comment: Are you using docker-desktop or docker toolbox (docker + virtualbox)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using docker toolbox on windows you can try to access kafka-manager with this address: http://192.168.99.100:9000

Note: 192.168.99.100 is the default ip address of VM which docker running on.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, there's a hypervisor, not a full VM. You can open the hyperV manager to look at it

You compose file needs a port forward

```
ports:
  - '9000:9000'
```

Comment: Sorry I forgot to add the link to the tutorial. I added it now. ports: 9000:9000 exists.

Comment: That should be all you need to connect to the webserver. Works fine with other containers, probably, so if it still isn't, then we need more logs

Comment: you might also want to see https://code.visualstudio.com/blogs/2020/03/02/docker-in-wsl2

Comment: I just gave you the command. Please come back after reading the Docker documentation on logging

Comment: I've added the logs. Please see my updated question.

Answer (score 2):

docker-compose.yaml is totally fine which is given in the tutorial. Can you do `docker-compose down` and then again bring up the docker-compose up?

Then try to browse http://localhost:9000 and you should be able to see it.

Possible errors:-

1. Port forwarding (already done in the docker-compose)
2. Instead of `HTTP`, you are opening `HTTPS` in the browser.

Comment: Can you please run any normal application on localhost and see if you can connect to it?

Comment: Can you check which ports are in use by running one of the below commands in Powershell
` Get-Process -Id (Get-NetTCPConnection -LocalPort portNumber).OwningProcess`

Comment: It says: No MSFT_NetTCPConnection objects found with property 'LocalPort' equal to '9000'.

Comment: Which means, Port is not mapped

Comment: So what should I do?